# Can a daemon server use Azure App Service`s provided built-in authentication?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

We are currently running our Web API using Azure App Service. So far no authentication was used or needed. Now we would like to add authentication to a single new method.

Azure build-in authentication is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). Since we want the data to be queried by another server (not running in Azure) without user interaction, [daemon server solution is considered](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon) . For this to work, it is necessary to create App registration for daemon application in Azure AD and edit the one that was created by built-in authentication for the Web API.

Following code is needed which requires several NuGet packages.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
}

private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Tenant = <tenant>,
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidAudience = <API address>
            }
        });
}
```

**Is there a way to combine these two approaches and have deamon server that acquires JWT token using its registration in Azure AD (this bit we have) and have this token validated by the built-in authentication (without using the code above) of the App Service?**

With the code above everything works, but once it is removed daemon`s JWT token is not recognized. In both cases (with/without the code) it is possible to manualy log in using built-in authentication on `<appAddress>/.auth/login/aad`. Build-in authenticating is described to take care of JWT tokens, but it doesn`t work.

Comment: App Service provides a built-in token store, which is a repository of tokens that are associated with the users of your web apps, APIs, or native mobile apps. From your server code, the provider-specific tokens are injected into the request header, so you can easily access them. From your client code, send an HTTP GET request to /.auth/me. The returned JSON has the provider-specific tokens. However, in your case the token generated in not a user token. Hence, token validated by the built-in authentication may not work in your case.

Comment: That`s disappointing, thanks for the information.